# Gracefully terminate a command line application on Windows

Tags: windows, process, taskkill

I'm creating a command-line application, which spawns a process (command defined by a user, usually an HTTP server) and when the application's job is done, I want to let the process know it should terminate.

In UNIX, I can do that by sending SIGTERM and if the process doesn't end, then I can kill it brutally by SIGKILL.

In Windows, I struggle to find an alternative to the SIGTERM scenario. I learned there's `taskkill /PID XXXX` (without `/f`!), but

1. I found no information about what `taskkill /PID XXXX` does under the hood, hence I can't test it. I can't find how to handle whatever `taskkill /PID XXXX` sends on the process side.
2. It doesn't seem to work with commands in `cmd.exe`. I tried to run a simple server process in one `cmd.exe`, get its PID and in another window to `taskkill /PID XXXX` it, but taskkill refused to do that: `ERROR: The process with PID XXXX could not be terminated. Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).`

So my question is: **How to inform a command-line process in Windows that it should terminate without forcefully terminating it? How to receive and act upon such message on the process-to-be-terminated side?**

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/151196/how-does-windows-kill-a-process-exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683155(v=vs.85).aspx) signals a console application as if the user had pressed Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break.  Console applications can ignore these signals (using [SetContolCtrlHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx)), but, by default, they just do an ExitProcess on themselves.

This is the same signal Windows uses when the user closes the console window, logs off, or shuts down.

Comment: Do you know how can I send these signals from a programming language, such as JavaScript (node.js)?

Comment: @HonzaJavorek:  Sorry, I do not.  Maybe you should add an appropriate language tag to the question to get the folks who do know to notice the question.

Answer (score 4):

TaskKill uses `PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);` (basically the same as pressing the X on a window) if the process has a visible window.

If you know the application is a console application you can use `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` instead.